# how to determine if website is opened on iPhone/Android browser or from iPhone/Android app web view?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webview, uiwebview

Objective is to identify website being opened in

- Device browser
- Or inside the native app web view.
- looking solution for both Android and iOS

Comment: Why do you want to do this and what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: I have to disable some feature on web site depending on if website is launched in native app or mobile browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**iPhone**

Change the UserAgent in the App

```
// Modify the user-agent
NSString* suffixUA = @"AppName";
UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; 
NSString* defaultUA = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
NSString* finalUA = [defaultUA stringByAppendingString:suffixUA];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:finalUA, @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

Now you could check it via Javascript:

```
function isIOS() {
    return /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}

function isIOSInApp() {
    return isIOS() && /AppName/i.test(navigator.userAgent); 
}
```

**For Android:**

**Activity onCreate**

```
this.webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(
    this.webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString() 
    + " "
    + getString(R.string.user_agent_suffix)
);
```

**Values.XML**

```
<string name="user_agent_suffix">AppName/1.0</string>
```

Now you could check it via Javascript:

```
function isAndroid() {
    return /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}

function() isNativeApp {
   return isAndroid() && /AppName\/[0-9\.]+$/.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mdetect.js file provided by mobileesp.
Check below link :
http://www.hand-interactive.com/detect/mobileesp_demo_javascript.htm